# Как удалить токен из vault?

Tags: безопасность, storage, vault

Как в vault удалить токен? Он был скомпроментирован. Можно ли это сделать через UI?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через UI сделать не получилось. Причина не установлена: нет вкладок для этого. Следует отметить, что в UI я заходил через [root-token](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/tokens). Возможно, прична в этом.

Для освещения всей проблемы сгенерируем новый root-token, а затем его отзовём.

Важно, во время генерации root-token. Вам обязательно нужен [Unseal Key](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/seal). К сожалению, без него ничего сделать не удастся. Если у Вас его нет, то скорее всего
доступ утерян безвозвратно вместе с данными. При условии, что нет других токенов.

## Unseal Key

Перед тем, как дать доступ к vault, сразу после старта хранилища, Вы получили json с набором `Unseal Key`. В этот же момент, Вы указали, какое количество ключей требуется для того, чтобы распечатать хранилище. В дальнейшем, такое же количество ключей Вам будет требоваться для того, чтобы проделывать все действия от имени root.

Логика в этом примерно такая. Получив эти ключи, они раздаются разным людям, без ведома которых нельзя сделать действие от имени root.

## Генерация

```
vault operator generate-root -init
```

Вы можете получить вот такую ошибку:

```
Error getting root generation status: Get https://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/generate-root/attempt: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8200: connect: connection refused
```

Эта ошибка говорит о том, что `vault` находится на сервере удалённом, а не на Вашей машине. Для того, чтобы указать `vault` расположение машины, следует сделать так:

```
VAULT_ADDR=http://1.2.3.4:5/ vault operator generate-root -init
```

Вы получите такой вывод:

```
A One-Time-Password has been generated for you and is shown in the OTP field.
You will need this value to decode the resulting root token, so keep it safe.
Nonce         1592d094-ffb1-9a26-92a1-a9ad5b734cae
Started       true
Progress      0/2
Complete      false
OTP           MXCtP0HIzPmbdtPSDALsknTtHS
OTP Length    26
```

Запишите `OTP`. Он потребуется для получения финального токена. Также потребуется `Nonce`. Он будет доступен на каждо

Затем, будет предложено ввести `Unseal Key`. После ввода Вы получите запись вроде этой:

```
Nonce       94021344-dga1-976e-28fe-a8fxs7b74285d
Started     true
Progress    1/2
Complete    false
```

говорит она о том, что введен 1 из двух ключей. В Вашем случае количество ключей, необходимых для генерации может быть другим. Необходимо ввести ещё 1. Введём его. Очевидно, он должен быть отличным от текущего. Иначе получим это:

```
Error posting unseal key: Error making API request.

URL: PUT http://1.2.3.4:5/v1/sys/generate-root/update
Code: 400. Errors:

* given key has already been provided during this generation operation
```

В случае успеха получим:

```
Nonce            94021344-dga1-976e-28fe-a8fxs7b74285d
Started          true
Progress         2/2
Complete         true
Encoded Token    AkQEE2gNPAoPHAcaFkE/NiYEXHYKCh09PD4
```

Для получения финального токена, следует воспользоваться следующей командой:

```
VAULT_ADDR=http://1.2.3.4:5/  vault operator generate-root -nonce 3a032bcb-cf2a-bb04-4d22-501c26c0d9c5 -otp qGvvvghzOBm6kWMQ3k8N7HAKGy -decode AkQEE2gNPAoPHAcaFkE/NiYEXHYKCh09PD4
```

Здесь мы используем `opt`, который получили на 1м шаге, `nonce`, а также `Encoded Token=AkQEE2gNPAoPHAcaFkE/NiYEXHYKCh09PD4` с последнего шага. В результате получим токен, который похож на этот:

```
s.rI2jsplQN724xV3Umj2jMUQm
```

Его можно использовать для входа в vault:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

## Отмена генерации

Если Вам потребовалось прервать процесс генерации, выполните

```
VAULT_ADDR=http://1.2.3.4:5/ vault operator generate-root -cancel
```

## Отзыв токена

```
VAULT_ADDR=http://1.2.3.4:5/ VAULT_TOKEN=s.rI2jsplQN724xV3Umj2jMUQm vault token revoke -self
```

## Обсуждение

Во время работы над решением этой проблемы, я активно переписывался с участниками [сообщества HashiCorp](https://t.me/ru_hashicorp) в телеграме. Там можно найти диалог по фразе:

> Привет. Подскажите, как в vault удалить токен? Он был скомпроментирован.

С ним можно ознакомиться. Много деталей есть там.